# opacity on linear gradient background-image

Tags: css

how can I set an opacity value, for example `opacity: 0.6` on a linear-gradient background-image?

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #00497a -26.48%,#003366 73.52%);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `rgba()` CSS macro

Comment: `background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,73,122,0.6) 26.48%, rgba(0,51,102,0.6) 73.52%)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `hexidecimal color-codes` with `rgba color-codes`:

```css
div {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,67,116,0.6) -26.48%, rgba(0,51,102,0.6) 73.52%);
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks alot! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use RGBa values:

```css
linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,73,122,0.6) 26.48%, rgba(0,51,102,0.6) 73.52%);
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the transparency of the picture itself in the background, without applying color, you can use the background mask property

```
background-image: url('path/to/your/image.jpg');
-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 40%, black 55%);
mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 40%, black 75%);
```

You can read more here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-masking-with-mask-image

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.9),rgba(0,0,0,0.9)), url('/image/r.jpg');
```